# django assign User to a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, web-applications

I want to assign a User to a Model in django, I created a custom User model and sign-up/sign-in Forms but now I want to Assign a User model to another model named Customer whenever a new user is Created Here he the Customer model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
User = models.OneToOneField(
    Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0', null=True, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(
    max_length=200, default=' ', null=True, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=' ', null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    if self.name == None:
        return "ERROR-CUSTOMER NAME IS NULL"
    return self.name
```

Note: I can assign the User manually in the Database and It lists All the Users but I want it to do it itself when a new user is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by setting the user in the Customer model when a user is created

```
Customer.objects.create(user=request.user, name=username, email=email, phone=phone)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to extend the User model, and add more fields rather than creating a new model (which has a User onetoonefiled in it).
Something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is the kind of approach I use in my projects.
Here you have the default User model fields:
[User model default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/)
You don't need to add these in your Profile class.

I based this on this article: [How to extend User Django Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

don't forget to add to the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

to see the Profiles in the  admin page

Comment: thanks but this is not a fit for me because I have three different kind of users

I have a model for admin, a model for Seller and a model for Customer.

Comment: if the difference is permissions, maybe you should add a field called role and/or a field called permissions and that's how you differentiate between users. But if the models are very different, maybe you should have separate models, but I think it will be difficult to work with. I might be wrong.

Comment: good thinking but it will be more difficult to work on if i do that currently im trying three individual models for each kind of user